# Symfony 3 pre-fill FileType field

Tags: php, symfony, controller, symfony-forms

I have a FileType field in my form :

```
$builder->add('letter', FileType::class,[
    'label'=>'DEMANDE_STATUS',
    'required'=>false,
]);
```

And I would like to pre fill this 'letter' field when I create the form in the controller.

I've tried this so far, to no avail :

```
$letter = null;
if (file_exists($path.'/letter.pdf'))
    $letter = new File($path.'/letter.pdf');
    $demandeForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\DemandePaiementType', null, ['data'=>[
        'letter' => $letter,
    ]]);
```

This method usually works when I want to pre-fill a Text field but not in this case sadly.

Any idea on how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can pre fill a HTML file input field. You can however display some message to the user that they already filled in this field. You can handle this in your twig template.

Comment: Okay. Then how do I do that in the twig template? I assume I'd have to use form variables?

Comment: Not sure if the value is filled for fileTypes, try: {{ dump(form.letter.vars.VALUE) }} if not you can always pass the entity to your template and do whatever.

Comment: The value is not filled indeed. Thanks anyway, I'll resort to your second solution.